# How to get value from JSON encode in PHP?

Tags: php, json, decode

i have searched and searched but i don't know where i'm wrong getting a value from JSON encode, can you help me? Please don't kill me, i'm a newbie :)

My php:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode("document.json", true);
$getit = $data["likes"];
```

My JSON:

```
[{
"title" : "MYTITLE",
"image" : "MYIMAGE",
"likes" : 0
}]
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help this is now working!

Comment: `json_decode()` takes a json encoded string as argument. Not a file name. So you need to user normal file handling operations to read the file content, then decode that. I suggest you start by reading the documentation of the tool you want to use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: if this is the case, then it should be `$data[0]['likes']`

Comment: You also need to update the way you access to $data, have a look at every answer you got and at @Thamilan comment.

Comment: Could you please add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', true); at the top of your script and post the output?

Answer (score 2):

`json_decode` expects an string, not an filename - so you have first get the contents of the given file. This could be easily achieved with `file_get_contents`.

Your current json structure contains an array(with currently only one element), which contains an object. So if you want the likes, you have to read the first element of the result array and of that(an associative array), the likes.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);
$likes = $data[0]['likes'];
```

If you have more than one object in the given json file, you could loop over the data with `foreach`

```
foreach ($data as $element) {
    echo "likes of {$element['title']}: {$element['likes']}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `json_decode` you have to pass JSON string, not a file name. Use `file_get_contents` to get JSON content and then decode it.

```
$data  = json_decode(file_get_contents('document.json'), true);
$getit = $data[0]['likes'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array of objects, you first need to access the first element of your array :

```
$data[0]
```

Then you can access the key you want :

```
$getit = $data[0]['likes'];
```

Plus, as stated in a comment above, you need to pass a string to json encode, here is an code sample that should suit your needs :

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('document.json'), true);

$getit = $data[0]["likes"];
```

Hope this helps.